# How To Read A Simple Switch In C# Short Hand

Tags: c#

I am looking at some C# code that looks foreign to me

```
  return Con.Value switch
            {
                CTypes.ISO => 776,
                CTypes.HiCube => 888,
                _ => 983,
            };
```

Can this be translated to...?

```
int value = 0;
If(CTypes.ISO)
{
  value = 776;
}
else if (CTypes.HiCube)
{
  value = 888;
}
else()
{
  value = 983;
}
```

Or is the code above something else?

Comment: Almost, it would actually be `if(Con.Value == CTypes.ISO)` and `else if(Conv.Value == CTypes.HiCube)` and just `else` without the `()`

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) you can see new syntax of switch.

For your question it shows exactly this

```
switch(Con.Value)
{
    case CTypes.ISO:
        return 776;
    case CTypes.HiCube:
        return 888;
    default:
        return 983;
}
```

And for your if else statement

```
int value = 0;
if(Con.Value == CTypes.ISO)
{
  value = 776;
}
else if (Con.Value == CTypes.HiCube)
{
  value = 888;
}
else
{
  value = 983;
}
return value;
```

Comment: Thanks! The new syntax sucks!

Comment: @user12847070 You are welcome ^^. I love it actually short and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're almost right.

Alternative is below:

```
int value = 0;
if(Con.Value == CTypes.ISO)
{
  value = 776;
}
else if (Con.Value == CTypes.HiCube)
{
  value = 888;
}
else
{
  value = 983;
}
return value;
```